# /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin: to the end of $PATH instead of at the top

Tags: cygwin

I'm trying to ICU code using the MSVC linker. However, launching Cygwin places the /usr/local/bin and /usr/bin in front of the path, causing link.exe to always call the Cygwin version, instead of the MSVC version. How can I fix this configuration issue? Currently, I launch the VS command prompt, then launch cygwin.bat.

> /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft
>   F#/v4.0:/cygdr ive/c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio
>   10.0/VSTSDB/Deploy:/cygdrive/c /Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0/Common7/IDE:/cygdrive/c/Progra m Files (x86)/Microsoft
>   Visual Studio 10.0/VC/BIN:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86 )/Microsoft
>   Visual Studio 10.0/Common7/Tools:/cygdrive/c/Windows/Microsoft.NET/F
>   ramework/v4.0.30319:/cygdrive/c/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v3.5:/cygdrive/c /Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio
>   10.0/VC/VCPackages:/cygdrive/c/Prog ram Files (x86)/HTML Help Workshop:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Vis ual Studio
>   10.0/Team Tools/Performance Tools:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Mic rosoft SDKs/Windows/v7.0A/bin/NETFX 4.0 Tools:/cygdrive/c/Program
>   Files (x86)/Mi crosoft SDKs/Windows/v7.0A/bin:/cygdrive/c/Program
>   Files/Common Files/Microsoft Shared/Windows
>   Live:/cygdrive/c/Windows/system32:/cygdrive/c/Windows:/cygdrive/c
>   /Windows/System32/Wbem:/cygdrive/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/cygd
>   rive/c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SQL
>   Server/100/Tools/Binn:/cygdrive/c/Progr am Files/Microsoft SQL
>   Server/100/Tools/Binn:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Microsoft  SQL
>   Server/100/DTS/Binn:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft
>   ASP.NET/ASP.N ET Web Pages/v1.0:/cygdrive/c/Program
>   Files/TortoiseHg:/cygdrive/c/Program Files 
>   (x86)/GtkSharp/2.12/bin:/cygdrive/c/Users/tim/AppData/Roaming/npm:/cygdrive/c/P
>   rogram Files (x86)/nodejs:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Common
>   Files/Intuit/QB POSSDKRuntime:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Git/cmd

ICU tells me to

> Ensure that the order of the PATH is MSVC, Cygwin, and then other
>   PATHs. The configure script needs certain tools in Cygwin (e.g. grep).

**Update.** My cygwin.bat looks like this:

> @echo off
>
> C: chdir C:\cygwin\bin
>
> bash --login -i

Not very helpful.

Comment: Does your `cygwin.bat` file set the `PATH` environment variable?

Comment: This should really be on superuser.com, but take a look at the .bash_profile file in your home directory. Your path is most likely set in there and you should be able to modify it.

Comment: Hmm, I looked at that too, but all I have is if [ -f "${HOME}/.bashrc" ] ; then
  source "${HOME}/.bashrc"
fi and .bashrc does not have too much either. Is there some default profile that prepends /usr/local/bin that I can make append instead?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For a default installation of Cygwin, PATH is set is /etc/profile. You can modify PATH so that /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin are appended rather than prepended.

```
# PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:${PATH}"
PATH="${PATH}:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin/"
```

Resulting in:

```
Setting environment for using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 x86 tools.

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC>c:\cygwin\cygwin.bat

tim@xxx ~
$ printenv PATH
/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft F#/v4.0:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86
)/Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0/VSTSDB/Deploy:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Mic
rosoft Visual Studio 10.0/Common7/IDE:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft
Visual Studio 10.0/VC/BIN:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studi
o 10.0/Common7/Tools:/cygdrive/c/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319:/cyg
drive/c/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v3.5:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Mic
rosoft Visual Studio 10.0/VC/VCPackages:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/HTML Hel
p Workshop:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0/Team Too
ls/Performance Tools:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SDKs/Windows/v7.0
A/bin/NETFX 4.0 Tools:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SDKs/Windows/v7.
0A/bin:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Common Files/Microsoft Shared/Windows Live:/cyg
drive/c/Windows/system32:/cygdrive/c/Windows:/cygdrive/c/Windows/System32/Wbem:/
cygdrive/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x8
6)/Microsoft SQL Server/100/Tools/Binn:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Microsoft SQL S
erver/100/Tools/Binn:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Microsoft SQL Server/100/DTS/Binn
:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft ASP.NET/ASP.NET Web Pages/v1.0:/cygdr
ive/c/Program Files/TortoiseHg:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/GtkSharp/2.12/bin
:/cygdrive/c/Users/tim/AppData/Roaming/npm:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/nodej
s:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Common Files/Intuit/QBPOSSDKRuntime:/cygdrive/
c/Program Files (x86)/Git/cmd:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin/

tim@xxx ~
$ which link
/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0/VC/BIN/link
```

Comment: I love it when I come back to the question I asked and answered.

Answer (score 6):

I think that a cleaner method is to use the `ORIGINAL_PATH` variable that is created in Cygwin’s `/etc/profile`. Instead of modifying this file, modify your `.bashrc` file to use `ORIGINAL_PATH` and then append `/usr/local/bin` and `/usr/bin`.

`.bashrc`:

```
export PATH=$ORIGINAL_PATH:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin
```

Then you don't have to modify the Cygwin installation files.

Comment: This is indeed a cleaner way to do it, without modifying `/etc/profile` (thus preventing future updates). However, it has only been possible since version 4.1-3 of `base-utils` (released after this question was originally asked). Also, environment variables shouldn't really be set in `.bashrc`: use `.bash_profile` or `.profile` to set environment variables in the login shell(s).